# GroupBox showing Binding warning in Output window

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have built a small project and while debugging I noticed the following warning in the Output window:

```
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead.
MultiBindingExpression:target element is 'Border' (Name=''); target property is 'OpacityMask' (type 'Brush')
```

I traced it down to being caused by a GroupBox and eventually created a new blank WPF project with only an empty GroupBox in MainWindow.xaml and I still get the above error.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<GroupBox>

</GroupBox>
```

Any help understanding why I am getting the warning would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any global resources such as in the Themes folder which are being applied?

Comment: Nope, no global resources that I know of. I just created a new blank WPF C# project and changed the default DataGrid element to a GroupBox element.

Comment: I created a blank wpf project in VS2013 .net 4.5 and put a groupbox in the MainWindow like you did. I don't get this warning...What versions are you using?

Comment: I just tried the same thing in VS2013 and I also do not get the error. It is only happening in a VS2015 wpf project.